# Is there a Grunt Task to Add a Background Image to All Images in Folder?

Tags: css, image, gruntjs

### Background

I have a large number of employee images for a website. Each one is a headshot, and the area around the head is transparent:

[image]

On the website, I apply a `background-image` to each `img`.

```
<img class="employee" src="employee_x.jpg" />

.employee {
    background:url('employee_background.jpg') center center / cover;
}
```

It ends up looking like:

[image]

This lets me easily change out the images in the future, for all of them. Problem is, the background downloads first and the site owner is complaining that it looks fake when the background loads first.

---

### Problem

I now need to combine all of them and resave the images, with the backgrounds and employee images saved together. I can do this with Photoshop or Paint.net, but it takes a lot of time to go through every single image.

---

### Goal

I want it to take a folder with `employee_background.jpg` and all the other employee photos and then resave all of them into a `production` folder, using the background.

```
employees/john_smith.png
employees/sally_norton.png
employees/bill_miller.png
employees/employee_background.jpg

---->

employees/production/john_smith.png
employees/production/sally_norton.png
employees/production/bill_miller.png
employees/production/employee_background.jpg
```

Is there a Grunt task that can do this for me?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a PhotoShop action (batched) or an Imagemagick script. Either of those would make quick work of a thing like that.

Comment: Steve, I've been looking at Imagemagick and it seems like while it's very good at overlays, it's not so great at underlays. My overlay would need to be the Imagemagick "Background", in order for it to preserve size, I think? Have you worked with Imagemagick before, in this capacity, and could point me towards any specific resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

There is no grunt plugin currently that can do this, unfortunately.